# Is there a meaningful use of the datastax object mapper?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, objectmapper

A few month ago I started developing applications with cassandra as database.

I decided for using the datastax Java driver. So far so good.
I started developing my applications, created tables and used the Object Mapper to map them to my entities.

After a while I figured out that my data model totally sucks, since you should model your tables by your queries.

Let's assume your application has a users table, where you want to identify your users by username and/or email.

Therefore you will end up with tables like:

- users_by_email
- users_by_name
- users_by_email_and_name

How would you be able to model this scenario with usage of the object mapper, without creating entities per table??

If this is not possible, what's then the reason for having an object mapper?

All the best

Answer (score 2):

The object mapper will not handle denormalization for you. It will just take your objects and handle the mapping of those to cql. It's primary purpose is to save you from writing cql statements yourself.

Comment: Hey, I think you didn't get that question. For sure it doesn't handle denormalization for me. But the regular way of using cassandra is by denormalizing your data. Thus I am questioning the purpose of the object mapper.

Comment: I think I answered your question.
"It's primary purpose is to save you from writing cql statements yourself."

Comment: Good point, the question now is, how do you handle your denormalized model with the object mapper. Since you would have to create a POJO for each of your tables right?